# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: spring-data-redis

Using spring-data-redis,there is a exception like this question title.
My spring config xml file is:
[image]
And use the annotation follow:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "data")
```

framework version :

```
<spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-data-redis.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring-data-redis.version>
<jedis.version>2.8.1</jedis.version>
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Please consider markdown code blocks for posting code snippets instead of an image. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`StringRedisSerializer` is only capable of converting `String` to `byte []` and back. Its usage as `keySerializer` for the `template` passed into the `CacheManager` is causing the issue. Maybe `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` would be a better choice here. 
Find more about `RedisSerializer` in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer).